# Sprite Orientation Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

The sprite should be moving from north to south when the screens orientation is portrait.
Yet the sprite is going from east to west in portrait mode. When the screens orientation is landscape the sprite moves from east to west and i'm very confused about this. I'm trying to make the sprite move from up to down.

Code controlling the sprite

```
- (void)addMonster:(CCTime)dt
{

monster = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"MarioTube_Body_Rev.png"];

int minY = monster.contentSize.height / 2;
int maxY = self.contentSize.height - monster.contentSize.height / 2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int randomY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

monster.position = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width + monster.contentSize.width/2, randomY);
[self addChild:monster];

int minDuration = 2.0;
int maxDuration = 4.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int randomDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

CCAction *actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:randomDuration position:CGPointMake(-monster.contentSize.width/2, randomY)];
CCAction *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];
[monster runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove,actionRemove]]];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after player around with it i figured out it was simply changing some of the "heights" and widths around

```
- (void)addMonster:(CCTime)dt
{

monster = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"MarioTube_Body_Rev.png"];

int minX = monster.contentSize.height/2 - monster.contentSize.height/2;
int maxX = self.contentSize.height;
int rangeX = maxX - minX;
int randomX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;

monster.position = CGPointMake(randomX, self.contentSize.height + monster.contentSize.height/2);
[self addChild:monster];

int minDuration = 2.0;
int maxDuration = 4.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int randomDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

CCAction *actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:randomDuration position:CGPointMake(randomX, -monster.contentSize.height/100)];
CCAction *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];
[monster runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove,actionRemove]]];

}
```